# Read text file and convert to object

Tags: c#, algorithm

i'm trying to read data from a text file, to create some object, and work with.

My text content is actually like this.

```
Server : V2JJFERPP98
ERROR 0  : 5039
ERROR 3  : 0
ERROR 4  : 1915
ERROR 8  : 0
ERROR 9  : 0

Server : V2JJFERPP99
ERROR 0  : 0
ERROR 3  : 0
ERROR 4  : 15
ERROR 8  : 0
ERROR 9  : 1

Server : V2JJFERPP100
ERROR 0  : 0
ERROR 3  : 1
ERROR 4  : 0
ERROR 8  : 0
ERROR 9  : 0

V2JJFERPP98 | Error parsing database
V2JJFERPP100 | can't create lof file
V2JJFERPP100 | can't read backup_01_03_2017
```

Basically, my goal is to get as many object as error report in the file. And then, get all cronjob error on a second part.

I already created an object for the first part, like this.

```
private string server { get; set; }
private int error0 { get; set; }
private int error3 { get; set; }
private int error4 { get; set; }
private int error8 { get; set; }
private int error9 { get; set; }
```

But now, I don't know how to proceed to get the object.

First, I was thinking about read the whole file, and put everything into a var, and then, use the regex to check the content.

I have also checked the possibility to read each line, and depending on the line beginning, start creating an object.

For both method, I don't have a real idea about how to do this.

I have tried a lots of things, but I think I'm 100% off, sicne it doesn't sound really complicated, but can't find a proper way to do it.

string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(missionFilePath);

```
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    // for each line, we gonna create a new MissionState object
    if (line.StartsWith("Serveur"))
    {
        // Server : V2JJFERPP98
        var server = line.Substring(9);
        // and now, how to get error, and know when the new/next object come?
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you look into using a text file parser?  There are plenty out there.  A quick search yielded this, e.g. https://textfileparsers.codeplex.com/

Comment: "how to get error" - read next lines. "how know when next object come" - they are split by empty lines in your example.

Comment: @rory.ap i will try this kind, but was embarassed about the end of file, when it come about cronjob log, which isn't an object anymore. But i'll give a try, if it's the best way to do.
Evk: Same as above, I wasn't sure about the end with log. Also, how to properly get these error and server by object (guess i'm missing some skill on algo)

Comment: I think you have a very defined language in that file. Take a look at Antlr to generate C# parsers, it's very easy to use.

Comment: @BartBartoman -- Evk won't get notified about your comment.  You can only ping one user at a time.  Separate out Evk's comment into a separate comment and use [at]Evk

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one structure to parse and just want to get a job done - you can parse it yourself, since it's quite simple. Otherwise, look for third party solutions to help you with that. Here is an example how to parse your file. First define a class:

```
class Server {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Error0 { get; set; }
    public int Error3 { get; set; }
    public int Error4 { get; set; }
    public int Error8 { get; set; }
    public int Error9 { get; set; }
    public List<string> CronJobErrors { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

Then parse right away:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var servers = new Dictionary<string, Server>(); // parse results are here
        using (var fs = File.OpenRead(@"G:\tmp\so\parse.txt")) {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(fs)) {
                string line;
                Server current = null;                    
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
                    // line break - end of server definition
                    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) {
                        if (current != null) {
                            servers.Add(current.Name, current);
                            current = null;
                        }
                        continue;
                    }
                    var cidx = line.IndexOf(':'); // split by colon
                    if (cidx >= 0) {
                        var name = line.Substring(0, cidx).Trim();
                        var value = line.Substring(cidx + 1).Trim();
                        // ugly switch
                        switch (name) {
                            case "Server":
                                current = new Server() {Name = value};
                                break;
                            case "ERROR 0":
                                if (current == null)
                                    throw new Exception("Invalid line"); // more details here, just example
                                current.Error0 = int.Parse(value);
                                break;
                            case "ERROR 3":
                                if (current == null)
                                    throw new Exception("Invalid line"); // more details here, just example
                                current.Error3 = int.Parse(value);
                                break;
                            case "ERROR 4":
                                if (current == null)
                                    throw new Exception("Invalid line"); // more details here, just example
                                current.Error4 = int.Parse(value);
                                break;
                            case "ERROR 8":
                                if (current == null)
                                    throw new Exception("Invalid line"); // more details here, just example
                                current.Error8 = int.Parse(value);
                                break;
                            case "ERROR 9":
                                if (current == null)
                                    throw new Exception("Invalid line"); // more details here, just example
                                current.Error9 = int.Parse(value);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        var tdix = line.IndexOf('|');
                        if (tdix >= 0) {
                            var name = line.Substring(0, tdix).Trim();
                            var value = line.Substring(tdix + 1).Trim();
                            if (servers.ContainsKey(name)) {
                                servers[name].CronJobErrors.Add(value);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }            
    }        
}
```